# what is the difference between these three constructors?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

```
List(); 

List( List const & ); 

List( List && );
```

Please tell me the difference between these three constructors (specially last two)?
actually i'm confused between List & and List && ?
what is the difference between  & and &&

Comment: It would be more productive for you to study some C++. This isn't a tutorial site. There's a list of good books [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming top-to-bottom:

**[Default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)**:

```
List();
```

**[Copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)** (where `const &` means it takes const lvalue reference):

```
List( List const & );
```

**[Move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)** (where `&&` means it takes non-const rvalue reference):

```
List( List && );
```